# Binding a URI to a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a property which is of type `System.URI`, and I have it bound to a textbox. This seems to work pretty well, except if I type something like https://stackexchange.com/ it will not let me enter the / because I'm getting:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'http://' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=webURL; DataItem='ItemViewModel' (HashCode=66245186); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') UriFormatException:'System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.UriTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   at MS.Internal.Data.SourceDefaultValueConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

I then tried a converter to convert the URI to a string thinking that was the problem:

```
public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    Uri input = value as Uri;
    if (input == null) return String.Empty;
    else return input.ToString();
}

public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    string input = value as string;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return null;
    else return new Uri(input, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
```

this is even worse because this actually bombs if the URI is not valid.

Is there a way to bind a URI directly to a textbox? or do I just have to use a "proxy" property in my viewmodel to hold the string value. The reason I want to bind directly to the URI is that I have IDataError validation, that is checking the URI for validity which works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented your converter and it worked, though I didn't have to use the `override` keyword.

My XAML was:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Converter:UriToStringConverter x:Key="UriStringToConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
             Margin="5"
             Text="{Binding Url, Converter={StaticResource UriStringToConverter}}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
               Margin="5"
               Text="{Binding Url, Converter={StaticResource UriStringToConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

and the `Url` property was defined as:

```
    private Uri url = new Uri("http://example.com");
    public Uri Url
    {
        get { return url; }
        set
        {
            url = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Url"));
        }
    }
```

where the class implemented the `INofifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Note that I had to initialise the Uri with a valid url otherwise it raised an exception. Even if I type in (e.g.) "test" it successfully converts that back to a Uri (albeit an invalid one).